# MVC Core String Array into Bind Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

So I have a controller where when I want to post a model, and I want to only bind certain fields. I want to extract the params array out of the [Bind] tag as it can get very long. How do I accomplish this? I am currently getting "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type" when I try the below code.

```
protected static readonly string[] BINDABLE = { "PartID", "InternalPartNum",  "ManufacturerPartNum" };

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create([Bind(BINDABLE)]PartModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewData["ObjectName"] = OBJECT_NAME;
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    _partDAO.Insert(model);
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Comment: Simply, you can't do this, which is a good part of the reason that `Bind` is such an anti-pattern. The best solution is to not use it at all. Use a view model instead. See: https://cpratt.co/bind-is-evil/

Comment: By default, when a controller is built through scaffolding, all of the model or view model properties are listed on the create and edit methods (some exceptions apply). Thus, you're right, the list can get quite long. However, based on what I see from your code above, you only have 3 properties you want to bind. That doesn't seem that long to me. So, I question if you understand that the bind attribute only applies to params you want to post to your data store.

Comment: So, if your model, or view model has 15 different params to it but you only want to 'update' three of them you don't need the entire list -- only the three. Is that helpful?

Comment: Alternatively, you might look into custom model binding using ModelBinder. This circumvents the default BInd attribute and allows you to roll your own -- your custom model binder would take the HTTP request and you can build code to parse it anyway that you want. But that's a bit of work. Stick to what Chris P suggested.

Comment: I have some models that will be needing 15+ fields on them for creating/editing. I don't want to have to modify them on the Create, Edit, etc post backs. I want them in a singular array that can just be reused and less chance of something getting missed.

Comment: Also, the bind attribute is needed for passing security tests/compliance/etc.

Answer (score 0):

For `Bind`, it could accept String, you could try workaroud below:

```
protected const string BINDABLE = "PartID,InternalPartNum" ;

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create([Bind(BINDABLE)]PartModel model)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: That no longer works in MVC Core. Each field needs to be a separate string.

Comment: @JarodD What is your .net core version?